# LaTEX: changing the format of citation in References to list authors' last name first

Tags: latex, bibtex, citations

It seems the format in the Reference section is a little off! Can you please show me how to format the citation to list authors' last name first?

Thanks all.

Here is the current form in the Reference section:

```
 C. B. Grimmond, A. Isard, and J. Belding. Development and evaluation of
     continuously weighing mini-lysimeters. Agricultural and Forest Meteorology,
     62(3-4):205{218, 1992.
```

I use BibDesk to organize the citation database. Here is what I am using in the TeXstudio:

```
 \documentclass[]{article}
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
 \usepackage[round]{natbib}

 \begin{document}


 \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
 \bibliography{/Users/me/Citation/citation}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change the Bibtex Bibliography style to 'acm' or 'apalike'

```
  \bibliographystyle{stylename}
  \bibliography{bibfile}
```

Read more about other styles: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibtex_bibliography_styles